# How to fetch transactions from a historical node older than 2 years ago?

Tags: transactions, jsonrpc-api, historical-data

I'm missing transactions from an archive node. I can fetch transactions related to a wallet and associated token/vote/stake accounts. For wallets that are younger the balance transfers and other actions sum up correctly to the Balance present in the latest block for every SPL Token and SOL.

The issue is - when I tested with some bigger wallets with more transactions and I found that the latest transaction received is from 2 years ago, which means I'm missing a lot of history for a wallet, since Solana mainnet-beta was launched in March 2020 as far as I remember.

What am I doing wrong, and what am I not considering?

For context: I'm using @solana/web3.js and typescript.

Comment: If you're using the public RPC endpoint at api.mainnet-beta.solana.com, all of the transaction data goes all the way back to genesis. Regarding the missing data, likely you're querying blocks that were uploaded before they included pre- and post- token balances.